# Grouping and repeating the grouped rows inside a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, pattern-matching

I'm interested in finding the quickest way of grouping the rows of a large matrix in sub-groups based on the position of non-zero elements in the first column and then repeating them number of times based on the value of the non-zero element. The final output matrix is the repeated (or expanded) matrix. An example is shown as an image below:
[image: Grouping and repeating (replicating or expanding) the rows of the matrix]
The first row, first element is always non-zero. one non-zero element in the first column can be followed by another non-zero element without being followed by zero. If a non-zero element is followed by zeros it is added to the group as shown in the figure. Length of a group is from one non-zero element until before the next non-zero element. Here is another example for more clarity.
[image: Another example for more clarity regarding Grouping and repeating]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What if the matrix starts with a `0`?

Comment: No, it will never start with zero.

Comment: Do nonzero entries appear singly in the first column?

Comment: Yes, it can. For example, first column -> {3,0,1,0,0,2,3,0,1}. Non-zero entities can be followed by other non-zero entity in this case {2,3}.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
m = {
   {3, 1, 2},
   {0, 5, 1},
   {1, 4, 2},
   {0, 6, 9},
   {0, 4, 7},
   {2, 6, 8}
  };

Flatten[ConstantArray[#, #[[1, 1]]] & /@ Split[m, #2[[1]] == 0 &], 2]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 3 & 1 & 2 \\
 0 & 5 & 1 \\
 3 & 1 & 2 \\
 0 & 5 & 1 \\
 3 & 1 & 2 \\
 0 & 5 & 1 \\
 1 & 4 & 2 \\
 0 & 6 & 9 \\
 0 & 4 & 7 \\
 2 & 6 & 8 \\
 2 & 6 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Here is the explanation for the above one-line code:

Flatten[ConstantArray[#, #[[1, 1]]] & /@ Split[m, #2[[1]] == 0 &], 2]

1. First, **Split** function scans through the matrix m by taking two consecutive rows (#1, #2) and checks for the condition such that the 2nd row's first element is equal to zero (#2[[1]] == 0&), if it is True then it will add it to the group, otherwise it will add a split and start a new group, thereby grouping the matrix as show in the above example figure in the question section.
2. Then, **ConstantArray** function is mapped (/@) onto the grouped (split) matrix such that it will replicate the grouped rows inside the matrix, "1st row's first element" (#[[1, 1]]) number of times, thereby replacing grouped rows with repeated rows.
3. Finally, **Flatten** function flattens out the resultant list by removing all the unwanted curly braces up to the 2nd level, thereby creating the final resultant matrix.

Answer (score 3):

This could be a starter for discussions:

```
A = RandomInteger[{0, 3}, {6, 3}];
idx = Pick[Range[Length[A]], Unitize[A[[All, 1]]], 1];
B = Join @@ MapThread[
    Join @@ ConstantArray[A[[#1 ;; #2]], A[[#1, 1]]] &,
    {
     idx,
     Append[Rest@idx - 1, Length[A]]
     }
    ];
```

Hm. Building the list of rows first and to read from `A` only once seems to be slightly faster.

```
idx = Pick[Range[Length[A]], Unitize[A[[All, 1]]], 1];
B2 = A[[
   Join @@ Join @@ MapThread[
      ConstantArray[Range[#1, #2], #3] &,
      {idx, Append[Rest@idx - 1, Length[A]], A[[idx, 1]]}
      ]
   ]];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. It works. I checked it for my application.

Comment: Great! You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

```
m = {{3, 1, 2}, {0, 5, 1}, {1, 4, 2}, {0, 6, 9}, {0, 4, 7}, {2, 6, 8}}
SequenceReplace[m, seq : {{x_ /; x > 0, __}, 
                   Repeated[{0, __}, {0, Infinity}]} :> Table[seq, x]]
Flatten[%, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Module[{m = #,  p = SequencePosition[#, {{Except[0], __}, {0, __} ...}]}, 
     Join @@ (Join @@ ConstantArray[m[[Span @@ #]], m[[#[[1]], 1]]] & /@ p)] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
a = {{3, 1, 2}, {0, 5, 1}, {1, 4, 2}, {0, 6, 9}, {0, 4, 7}, {2, 6, 8}};

MatrixForm /@ {a, f @ a}
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
b = RandomInteger[3, {7, 3}];

MatrixForm /@ { b, f @ b}
```

[image]